# Sorting arrays (Bubble Sort)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a small doubt while sorting arrays and yeah I am new to programming. Take a look at this code for example:

```
public void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
boolean swapped = true;
int j = 0;
int tmp;
while (swapped) {
    swapped = false;
    j++;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - j; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = tmp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, why do we have to use `j++` and `i < (array.length-j)` as the test expression? We could have rather used `i < (array.length)` as the test expression while omitting the variable `j`. Any answers?

Answer (score 0):

*"Why do we have to use j++ and i < (array.length-j) as the test expression?"*

The reason behind is at any time elements `array[ array.length -j ]` to `array[array.length - 1]` are already sorted.

---

Example:  Say you have array of length `n`.

So after the first iteration the biggest element will be placed at `array[n - 1]`.
 So because the largest element is already sorted on the next iteration we will only sort array of length `n - 1`.

After the second iteration the second biggest element will be placed at `array[ n - 2]`.

So because the 1st largest and 2nd largest elements are already sorted on the next iteration we will only sort array of length `n - 2`, and so on...

The running time of the algorithm will be [image: n2/2] which is [image: O(n2)]

As you said it we could have used `i < (array.length - 1)` but we will be just doing a lot of work for nothing. If we do this the running time will be (n*n) which is O(n*n). But though the running time is still O(n*n) but it is obvious that [image: n2/2] is smaller than [image: n2], hence the first one is efficient.

Comment: When I don't consider **j**, I get the following error:

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Comment: Yeah read the answer very well I am sure it will help you a lot. yeah you have to use `i < (array.length - 1)`

Comment: Thanks a ton! That really helped!!

Comment: You may want to put a backslash before your asterisks so they are displayed rather than causing italics. (too small an edit to be allowed to fix myself).